# PTIJ: may Jews time travel and sin in the past before Yom Kippur

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

There is a mitzvah to ask for  forgiveness from somebody you’ve wronged on Erev Yom Kippur. Also the Mishnah in [Yoma 8:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Yoma.8.9?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi) states

> With regard to one who says: I will sin and then I will repent, I will sin and I will repent, Heaven does not provide him the opportunity to repent, and he will remain a sinner all his days. With regard to one who says: I will sin and Yom Kippur will atone for my sins, Yom Kippur does not atone for his sins. Furthermore, for transgressions between a person and God, Yom Kippur atones; however, for transgressions between a person and another, Yom Kippur does not atone until he appeases the other person. Similarly, Rabbi Elazar ben Azarya taught that point from the verse: “From all your sins you shall be cleansed before the Lord” (Leviticus 16:30). For transgressions between a person and God, Yom Kippur atones; however, for transgressions between a person and another, Yom Kippur does not atone until he appeases the other person. In conclusion, Rabbi Akiva said: How fortunate are you, Israel; before Whom are you purified, and Who purifies you? It is your Father in Heaven, as it is stated: “And I will sprinkle purifying water upon you, and you shall be purified” (Ezekiel 36:25). And it says: “The ritual bath of Israel is God” (Jeremiah 17:13). Just as a ritual bath purifies the impure, so too, the Holy One, Blessed be He, purifies Israel.

What about repenting with the intention to time travel back before that repentance and transgress?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: From a purely halachic standpoint, what's the problem? If someone was murdered, and then the clocks were wound back and he never died, what sin is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is addressed by Rav Nachman in his [Sichos HaRan 85:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Sichot_HaRan.85.3?ven=Rabbi_Nachman%27s_Wisdom,_trans._Aryeh_Kaplan,_Jerusalem._Breslov_Research_Institute,_1973&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> רַק שֶׁיִּזָּהֵר לִהְיוֹת שָׁמוּר מִן הָעֲבֵרָה ח"ו, אֲבָל כְּשֶׁהוּא רַק שָׁמוּר מִן הָעֲבֵרָה ח"ו, אֲזַי כָּל אָדָם מְתַקֵּן בְּכָל מָקוֹם שֶׁהוּא נוֹסֵעַ לְשָׁם. אֲפִלּוּ אִישׁ פָּשׁוּט לְגַמְרֵי
>
> You must only be careful not to sin while you are there. If you do not sin, you can correct things wherever you travel.